# Apiary: Refer to multiple models in a body

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

It seems you can only refer to the model itself in an unmodified form from a payload/body section:

```
# Item [/]
+ Model

        { "name" : "an item" }

## GET
+ Response 200

    [Item][]
```

Is there any way to return an array of the model or use the model as a field? I.e. something like

```
+ Response 200

{ "items" : [ [Item][], [Item][] ]}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916227/reuse-a-resource-model-as-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible yet.

It should be available soon using [Traits](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/47).