# Given an API blueprint resource model, how can I ensure that the readonly part of a resource is not updatable?

Tags: apiblueprint

I have a large model which I am using for both GET and PUT on a resource.
The model includes an "audit" object like so:

```
            "audit": {
                "createdAt": "2014-04-14T02:15:15Z",
                "lastUpdatedAt": "2014-04-14T02:15:15Z",
                "deletedAt": ""
            }
```

This is obviously a readonly part of the resource - is there any way to show this in the contract model so "audit" appears for the GET response representation but not the PUT request representation?

The only alternative I can see is to copy the model into the body of the PUT and remove the readonly parts - but that then eliminates the benefit of having a single model that is reusable across different methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible yet. Capabilities of current resource model are very limited. It's similar issue as [Apiary: Refer to multiple models in a body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014115/apiary-refer-to-multiple-models-in-a-body) or [Reuse a resource model as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916227/reuse-a-resource-model-as-an-array).

There are plans to address this need and make blueprints more DRY in the future - See the [Embedded Assets](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/29) and [Traits](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/47) milestones.

Solution is to either copy & paste, or, in your particular case, not to return different payloads in GET and PUT. Why are you doing it?

Comment: > Why are you doing it?  
it doesn't make sense to include the "audit" object in the *request* representation for PUT.  the response would include the audit object but not the request.